# Can Awakened Spellbook borrow bludgeoning/piercing/slashing damage from the Magic Weapon spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-types

For the purpose of the damage type swap feature of the Order of Scribes Wizard's Awakened Spellbook feature, does the +1 bonus to damage rolls from the *Magic Weapon* spell qualify as bludgeoning/slashing/piercing damage?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### *Magic Weapon* has no damage type

The [*magic weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-weapon) spell description says:

> You touch a nonmagical weapon. Until the spell ends, that weapon becomes a magic weapon with a +1 bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls.

The spell does not mention any damage type, and has no damage type. The weapon that is enchanted has a damage type, and the additional damage will be of the weapon's, not the spell's type.

Therefore, there is nothing to swap here with Awakened Spellbook.